# Error on ASP.NET Websites. Connection Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, connection, database-connection

I have suddenly got this error on a couple of my sites, and I'm not sure what the problem is. 
These sites have been up and runnnig for over 2 years now and this is the first time I'm seeing this error.

"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 
XX.XX.XXX.XXX:80"

The stack trace is as follows.

```
[SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond XX.XX.XXX.XXX:80]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +239
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP) +35
   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) +224

[WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) +1867457
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() +13
   Controls_IpConfigInner.stripConfig(String strClientIp) +136
   Controls_IpConfigInner.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +86
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

The trace tells me it has got something to do with sockets, but there is no socket programming.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall?. Maybe it is ON and you had it disabled

Comment: The firewall is ON, however I do have other wesbites running on the server. They are able to connect to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using a socket directly, but you are making a remote web request which uses a socket internally because that is how one does networking stuff on most platforms. Since there is a networking issue you see the socket exception at the end of the day.

That error translates to "I could not open a connection to the remote server. Check the address, make sure it is listening on the appropriate port and make sure we aren't firewalled please."

Comment: Hi Wyann, I checked from the server, I was able to ping the address for the database.  There are other websites as well on this server and they seem to be working fine. This is just happening for a couple of them. Also, is the IP I am trying to ping supposed to show up where I've X'd out the numbers? we dont have this IP on any of our network!

Comment: Wyann != Wyatt; This isn't a database connection that is the problem -- unless your database is taking web requests. Note the caller (System.Net.HttpRequest) and the port (80). Are you talking to a web service?

Comment: Yep, most of the webservices arent working as well, what could be the problem, and what can I do to fix it ?

Comment: No idea directly -- I don't have the code nor the environment. Looking at the error I would start at line 136 in controls/ipconfig_inner to start with as that seems to be what is triggering the error. If it has been working for 2 years I would also start by asking ops "what changed recently?"